# css and html. How to display two divs in one row

Tags: html, css

This is a very simple question: I have two elements that should be displayed in one row at a specific ratio. Then the same pattern should be repeated in a next row. However, the content of the subsequent row is printed in unused space of the previous row.The problem is obviously the css file.

I guess the example will make it clear:

```css
.row1 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syle.css">
</head>
<div>
  <div class="paragraph1">
    <h1> Paragraph 1 </h1>

    <h3> subtitle1 </h3>
    <div class="row1">
      <p class="row1_col1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row1_col2">
      <p> Just some other text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="paragraph1">
    <h1> Paragraph 1 </h1>

    <h3> subtitle1 </h3>
    <p class="row1_col1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <div class="row1_col2">
      <p> Just some other text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Didn't understand what do you try to achieve, please add fiddles/plunker more explanations the problem.

Comment: Floats are historically a headache to work with and can get a bit messy. I would suggest looking into using some of the more modern techniques, such as flexbox and I think you'll be a lot happier with the results in the long run. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. P.S. if it seems like your styles aren't working, the style sheet you're linking is is spelled "syle.css", and it's possible you meant "style.css".

Comment: Thanks. The flexbox was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less than elegant solution (Full code in link)

https://jsfiddle.net/qk7o8w4t/1/

```
.paragraph {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float:left;
}
```